# VSTACK google sheets function doesn't work

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vstack, hstack

Suddently, the Google Sheets functions VSTACK and HSTACK don't work any more.

Any Idea why? I'm in Colombia right know and the google account that I use is in Spanish. But I used to use those functions, even they have google documentation.

The following is the sheets fuction that I used:
=VSTACK($B$2:$B$8,B9:B15)

[image]

Comment: Answered here: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/202500036?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

They were likely temporarily rolled back during their launch for some quick fixes. Try again and they should be available now as it’s been some time since the initial rollout.

Comment: @Student-22141 has the VSTACK function returned?